# Star Chromatic Index of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any articles available about star chromatic index of graphs, excluding the star chromatic index of subcubic graphs? Im having problems due to lack of  literature on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a number of papers published in 2018 for other classes of graphs. A presentation of this topic can be found [here](http://doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.28876.72321). There is still a lot of research going on mainly due to the open question about the star chromatic index of complete graphs.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your answer! Are there any permanent references you can provide, in case this link eventually stops working?

Comment: Hi! I have edited my post by providing a doi link to the slides. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 0):

You could [try this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.21644/full) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065316300683) as a start.